# Problems with SOAP/WSDL/System.Web.Services and Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, windows-phone-8, wsdl

I have an old WindowsCE phone app. I want to create a similar application for the Windows Phone 8. My initial plan was to reuse my old C# code, especially for the business model and spend new effort for the new UI/UX.

My business logic was based on a WSDL SOAP web service. I have a java web server that published the WSDL, I added a Web Reference to the old Visual Studio and my communication between the two peers (client/server) was well.

However in Visual Studio 2013 plenty of things are different. In particular some base headers are missing. For example System.Web.Service is accessible when using the latest 4.5 SDK framework.

Is there any chance to reuse my old code. Can I have two separate projects in my solution? For example the old code could be decoupled from the primary project. Can somehow create an external library that triggers the web service with the old code and include that library in the Windows Phone 8 app?

Comment: @verdesrobert could you please elaborate further? Would you need additional info?

Comment: is it possible that you post some parts of your service and/or client implementation

Comment: Please look this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911301/how-do-i-use-reference-cs-after-creating-a-service-reference-svcutil-does-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any chance to reuse my old code. Can I have two separate projects in my solution? For example the old code could be decoupled from the primary project. Can somehow create an external library that triggers the web service with the old code and include that library in the Windows Phone 8 app?

Some how yes but you must re-write most of the part of Client witch makes the connection to the service

> My business logic was based on a WSDL SOAP web service. I have a java web server that published the WSDL, I added a Web Reference to the old Visual Studio and my communication between the two peers (client/server) was well.

If you already had a layer in between ServiceReference and your View you can port that Layer as interface and make the implementation in a WP8 (Maybe even Portable) Class Library so that you can use it in the WP8 project

Answer (score 0):

*In particular some base headers are missing.*

You can use

public class SoapHeader : MessageHeader
    {
        protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            base.OnWriteStartHeader(writer, messageVersion);
        }

```
    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("xx");
        writer.WriteXmlAttribute("xmlns", "http://xx");
        writer.WriteString("xx");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
```

SoapHeader authSoapdHd = new SoapHeader();
                BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);

```
            MyPrintWebServiceSoapClient ws = new MyPrintWebServiceSoapClient();

            ws.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(xxx.asmx"));
            ws.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(6000);

            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(ws.InnerChannel))
            {
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(authSoapdHd);
                ws.LogInCompleted += ws_LogInCompleted;

                LogInRequest request = new LogInRequest(xxx, yyy);
                ws.LogInAsync(request);
            }
```